# How do I parse JSON using the Cocoa API?

Tags: json, cocoa

I'm just learning to code in Xcode, so the question can be quite easy)

I have an example of code:

```
NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                      [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gooruism.com/feed/json"]];

id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
    NSString *title_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Now I want to parse values from my own JSON that looks like this:

```
        {
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 14,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "carinspect",
      "_type" : "inspect",
      "_id" : "ZEDrkX9AQXKsZYdFr02ilw",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "UserID" : [ 2 ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "carinspect",
      "_type" : "inspect",
      "_id" : "778xOLe6Qy-jvnQUzmhADA",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "UserID" : [ 2 ]
      }
    },
```

How can I change

1. The array from where the data is taken from `id jsonObjects` to something like `hits.hits jsonObjects`
2. Get the _id value (something like `NSString *title_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"_id"];`)
3. Get the value of UserID (like `NSString *title_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"fields.UserID"];`)

Sorry if the language I'm trying to explain is awful

Comment: You generally don't want to sequence through an NSDictionary (representing a JSON "object") using `for(x in y)`, but instead want to explicitly name the elements you want to fetch -- `NSDictionary* hits = jsonObjects[@"hits"];`.

Comment: (I strongly suspect that you got the above code by blindly copying code you didn't understand (but which was parsing a JSON "array").  Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes to learn, and you're doomed if you don't understand it.)

Comment: @AndreyPopov what is the issue? you dont know how to parse this JSON?

Comment: @meda Sorry, just learning...

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe I'm wrong, but under hits.hits I have an array I want to run through..?

Comment: Yes, but you gotta get there first.  Peel the onion.

Comment: please search SO before posting - parsing JSON is .... like.... one the most often asked about objC topic ;) [right after date formatters]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                      [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXXXXXXX.com"]];

id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

id jsonHits = [[jsonObjects objectForKey:@"hits"] objectForKey:@"hits"];

for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonHits) {
    NSString *title_data = [[dataDict objectForKey:@"_source"] objectForKey:@"Number"];
```